# GNOME 45 calendar - first day of the week

Tags: gnome, calendar, gnome-calendar

I am using GB locale

```
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
```

and looking into /usr/share/i18n/locales

```
LC_TIME
abday       "Sun";"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat"
...
first_weekday 2
END LC_TIME
```

seems all fine: [in the applet also shows right, starting with Monday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxIcw.png)

**But in GNOME calendar it is
[still starting with Sunday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Kya.png)**
and since there is no specific option for this in GNOME calendar I am out of ideas.

I also tried to reinstall the calendar, but was not helping.
Other calendars (e.g. Evolution's) are working fine, starting with Monday.

I am quite new to Linux, all ideas are welcome.

<s>Edit: after @steeldriver comment, I checked, and the calendar was installed via the 'App Center'.
Now I reinstalled it from the 'Software' application (still DEB, not flatpak, not snap) - and it works perfectly.</s>

But as far as I know the App Center should be the new way for installing apps. So I am not sure whether this needs further reporting or something just went off in my local system.
(I also noticed that the app icon it not working well in the App Center way, while having no issues in the Software way. )

[image]

**Edit2: well, my eyes need further training, it was a snap installation, and the deb package fixed the issue.**

[image]

Comment: Is it correct if you start it from a terminal with the locale explicitly i.e. `LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 gnome-calendar` ?

Comment: @steeldriver this is what I get:
(gnome-calendar:85140): Adwaita-WARNING **: 17:28:53.902: No known Yaru accent 'orange'

(gnome-calendar:85140): Adwaita-WARNING **: 17:28:53.934: No known Yaru accent 'orange'

(gnome-calendar:85140): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 17:28:54.307: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: This call is not available inside the sandbox

(gnome-calendar:85140): GcalWeatherService-WARNING **: 17:28:54.670: Could not create GCLueSimple: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: Location services disabled

Comment: Did you install gnome-calendar as a flatpak or snap? if so, please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think it came with the OS installation.
Nevertheless I checked, and it was installed via the 'App Center'. 

Now I reinstalled it from the 'Software' application (still DEB, not flatpak, not snap) - and it is good there, kinda strange

Comment: I checked further, it was a snap installation after all, my eyes just couldn't see it.